# C++ free error with vector instantiated with fill constructor

Tags: c++, stdvector, free

I am attempting to create a vector of a desired size, and then reuse the vector's memory for multiple iterations of a loop. I use the "fill" vector constructor to set the vector to a desired initial capacity.

When I refer to the "fill" constructor, I mean what cplusplus.com refers to as the "fill" constructor (see [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)):

> (2) fill constructor
> Constructs a container with n elements. Each element is a copy of val (if provided).

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error (see my example below for full details):

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

To simplify the problem, I created the following minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int k = 1;

    std::vector<int> values{(2*k+1) * (2*k+1)};
    int num_items = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2*k+1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2*k+1; ++j) {
            std::cout << "Before assignment: " << num_items << std::endl;
            values[num_items] = 0;
            num_items++;
            std::cout << "After assignment: " << num_items << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "At end, num_items is " << num_items << std::endl;
}
```

When I run this, this is the full output:

```
Before assignment: 0                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 1                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 1                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 2                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 2                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 3                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 3                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 4                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 4                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 5                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 5                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 6                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 6                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 7                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 7                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 8                                                                                                                                                                  
Before assignment: 8                                                                                                                                                                 
After assignment: 9                                                                                                                                                                  
At end, num_items is 9                                                                                                                                                               
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001f00c20 ***                                                                                                     
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Since the program had the invalid free *after* the last print statement executed successfully, my assumption is the invalid free occurs when the vector is deallocated. I do not understand why this would happen though. I also know from my print statements that I never assign to an index outside the bounds of the vector's size.

I know the way this example looks, I could have just used `push_back()` instead of setting the vector's size with the fill constructor. However, this is just a minimal reproducible example - in my real code, I am creating my vector once, and then reusing the memory (overwriting the values in my vector each time).

If it still isn't clear why I can't just use `push_back()`, let me know in the comments, and I can update my answer to improve clarity.

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger to inspect what's in the constructed `std::vector`. Your debugger will show exactly what was actually constructed, and make it crystal clear what the problem is. This is exactly what a debugger is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you claim is "the full output" isn't the full output of the program you show, since that contains an output of `values.size()` which should be `1`. And that is also what leads to the problem you're having: You have a vector of a single element, and access it out of bounds, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

If you initialize `std::vector` using curly-braces it will be using the `std::initializer_list` [constructor of `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

If you want the vector to be initialized with `(2*k+1) * (2*k+1)` number of elements, you need to use parentheses instead:

```
std::vector<int> values((2*k+1) * (2*k+1));
```

Comment: I thought the preferred way to initialize objects is to use `{}` syntax instead of `()` syntax?

Comment: In this instance, the `initializer_list` syntax will initialize the vector with a literal, as opposed to a vector with the desired number of elements.

Comment: @ShaneBishop A list inside curly-braces means [*list initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which for objects having a constructor-overload using [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (which `std::vector` have) then that will be used.